# where is the underscore in my CheckBox?

Tags: checkbox, javafx, javafx-8

The shortest possible program to show my problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestCheckBox extends Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("ABC_DEF"), new CheckBox("ABC_DEF"));
        ((StackPane) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

leads to:

[image]

In SceneBuilder by comparison it´s displayed normally, but not in my application. I am running Java 1.8.0-b129

Any hint?

Comment: Looks like a defect in JavaFX to me. But not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably want to [setMnemonicParsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#mnemonicParsingProperty) to `false` on the CheckBox.

> MnemonicParsing property to enable/disable text parsing. If this is set to true, then the Label text will be parsed to see if it contains the mnemonic parsing character '_'. When a mnemonic is detected the key combination will be determined based on the succeeding character, and the mnemonic added.
>
> The default value for Labeled is false, but it is enabled by default on some Controls.

Comment: works fine with setting setMnemonicParsing to false...thanks!