# JavaFX - Can't use underscores in MenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, menuitem

I was creating a progrma with JavaFX when I came across a very strange problem. I wanted to create a MenuItem with a text that contains underscores (_), but when that text is displayed the underscores disappear. Here is an example code:

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Test_underscore");
        menu.getItems().add(item);

        mainPane.setTop(menuBar);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane, 890, 570));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Instead of displaying "Test_underscore", it displays this:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: Can you look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079618/where-is-the-underscore-in-my-checkbox) and see if it solves your problem? I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, since `MenuItem` doesn't extend `Labeled` so the method might by present. Edit: While it doesn't extend `Labeled`, it seems the method is still declared for `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the [`mnemonicParsing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#mnemonicParsingProperty--) property is `true` for the item, underscores receive special treatment. Setting this property to `false` prevents this:

```
item.setMnemonicParsing(false);
```