# JavaFX - First underscore on a node's text does not render

Tags: java, javafx

This is a really strange bug, but anytime I try to put text with underscores on any JavaFX node **besides** Labels (Buttons, Checkboxes, etc) the first underscore is never rendered.

Simple example to illustrate my point:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            TilePane tp = new TilePane();
            root.setCenter(tp);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Button b = new Button("Underscores_Do_Not_Show_Right");
                tp.getChildren().add(b);
            }

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:
[image: The first underscore is missing for each button]

This seems like a JavaFX bug, but does anyone know of a workaround? For Checkboxes I simply put a Label next to a text-less Checkbox. With Buttons, however, this is not an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Buttons have a [`mnemonicParsingProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#mnemonicParsingProperty), you should disable that property to avoid underscores being interpreted as mnemonics. Like so:

```
b.setMnemonicParsing(false);
```

Comment: In clear text: you with "..._D..." you could do a selection by typing D. Sometimes the mnemonics, D, is underscored.

Comment: Wow, can't believe the fix is that simple. Will accept as answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

##### Soln 1

*As above answer post said:*

- `b.setMnemonicParsing(false);`

##### Soln 2

*Online resources are very limited, I didnt find the documentation for following.*

- You can escape it by using **an extra underscore as escape character**.

  eg:: `Button button = new Button("CC__DD");`
- Though, the **next underscore** (if you have) will be chosen to be mnemonic.

  So you may need to escape **every** single one.
- `Button button = new Button("CC__DD__EE_FF");`

  will **throw**

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 10, end 11, length 10
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4602)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2705)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.layoutLabelInArea(LabeledSkinBase.java:590)
  ```

  Idk why, seems a bug to me.

##### related links

> [JDK-8125091] RadioButton eats first underscore from it's text - Java Bug System 
> https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8125091 
>
> java - JavaFX - Can't use underscores in MenuItem - Stack Overflow 
> [JavaFX - Can't use underscores in MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117694/javafx-cant-use-underscores-in-menuitem) 
>
> [] 
> Menu Mnemonics 
>
> A small difference between SWT und JavaFX is how you define a mnemonic key for menus and menu items. Where SWT uses the “&” character JavaFX expects you to use the underscore “_” instead. 
> <> 
> http://www.kware.net/?p=64 
>
> [] 
> An ampersand (&) may be used in the button name to underline one of its letters. For example: \
>
> ```
> Gui, Add, Button,, &Pause
> ```
>
> In the example above, the letter P will be underlined, which allows the user to press Alt+P as [shortcut key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Gui.htm#ShortcutKey). To display a literal ampersand, specify two consecutive ampersands (&&). 
> <> 
> https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControls.htm#Button